# Div will not stay inside frame

Tags: css

I have a div that will not stay put, it travels outside of the parent. The div I'm having trouble with is marked "6". It travels outside the parent to the right.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html{
       border:1px solid;
       height:99%;
      }
      body{
       height:100%;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
      }
      #pageWrapper{
       padding:0;
       margin:0;
       height:100%;
       position:relative;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pageWrapper">
      <div style="width:50%;border-right:0px solid;height:100%;float:left;position:relative;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:30%;border:1px solid;">1</div>
        <div style="width:100%;height:40%;border:1px solid;">2</div>
        <div style="width:100%;height:30%;position:absolute;bottom:0;border:1px solid;">3</div>
      </div>
      <div style="width:50%;border:0px solid;height:100%;float:right;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:40%;border:1px solid;">4</div>
        <div style="width:100%;height:40%;border:1px solid;">5</div>
        <div style="width:100%;height:20%;position:absolute;bottom:0;border:1px solid;">6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hay, Nach, divs 3 and 6 should be on the floor of the parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add position:relative to the parent div or remove position:absolute from the div you marked

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed that! I'll credit you for your answer when the time expires.

Comment: Of course Pal, I'd accept it now but stackoverflow says I have to wait 6 more minutes before I can accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `position:absolute;bottom:0` on the lower two divs - It's unnecessary and causes your erratic behaviour.

Comment: Florian, if I get rid of the position:absolute, how will the divs stay down?

Comment: The stay down because they are aligned one after another? See: http://jsfiddle.net/Cxg5S/

Comment: Thank you Florian. I see what you mean. Because I'm using 100% height and all containers within the parent total 100% height, the bottom divs will always be on the floor. So the need for absolute positioning is unneeded. I upped your post.